# ActionListener "not abstract and does not override" error

Tags: java, swing, overriding, actionlistener, abstract

I keep getting the "is not abstract...." error, I've searched around and tried @Override, but it doesn't work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I just followed a youtube video. Thanks.

```
JButton delete = new JButton("delete");
delete.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,25));
delete.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ //this line gets the error
public void actionperformed(ActionEvent e){
} 
});
```

Comment: can you post the exact error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that is your exact code, then try `actionPerformed` instead of `actionperformed` (note the capital `P` in `Performed`). The compiler seems the be complaining, that you fail to provide an implementation of the method [`actionPerformed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html#actionPerformed%28java.awt.event.ActionEvent%29) (declared in `ActionListener`, of which you create an instance by virtue of anonymous inner classes) due to this typo.